# Cakephp how to access App.imageBaseUrl from Cake Shell Script

Tags: shell, cakephp, constants

As the question says, how can i access the constant App.imageBaseUrl from my Cake Shell script?
My Cake Shell script sends of some HTML emails using cake email templates and it needs to get the path to the img folder constant using App.imageBaseUrl.

The constant is described here
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/global-constants-and-functions.html

Cheers
Kevin

Comment: It's not a constant, it's a configuration value. **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#Configure::read**

Answer (score 0):

In your email configuration block of code you should read the constant and pass it to email template through viewVars.

```
$Email = new CakeEmail();
$Email->viewVars(array(
    'imageBaseUrl' => YOUR_CONSTANT
));
```

[Email utility](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html)

Answer (score 0):

@ndm's comment is correct. It's a config setting that you can set manually. If that's all you need then you just set it to whatever you want with `Configure::write('App.imageBaseUrl', 'whatever');`

But if you're trying to avoid hard-coding the URLs then this doesn't really solve your problem. What I do in this situation is pass the URL to the shell script as a parameter. That way the same code can run on any environment.